# Can I get a user by their username and password using Doctrine (findOneBy()) on Symfony 4?

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I want to get a user by their username and password using Doctrine (`findOneBy()` method), on Symfony4.

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
        algorithm: argon2i
```

```php
$username= $request->request->get('username');
$password = $request->request->get('password');
$user= $this->em->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy([
    'username'=>$username,
    'passsword'=>$password
]);
return  new Response($user);
```

Comment: youseef, remember you can accept an answer if it solves your issue

Answer (score 4):

The correct way to do this is to fetch the user by their username, and then verify the password using Symfony's password encoder.

E.g.:

```php
public function __construct(UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder) {
    $this->encoder = $encoder;
}

public function yourAction(Request $request) {
    $username = $request->request->get('username');
    $password = $request->request->get('password');
    $user     = $this->em->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(['username'=>$username]);

    if ($user === null) {
        // user not found
        // throw exception or return error or however you handle it
    }

    if (! $this->encoder->isPasswordValid($user, $password)) {
        // invalid password
        // throw exception, or return error, or however you handle it
    }

//...
}
```

Remember that you would need to add the `use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;` statement at the top of your script, or you'll get a "class not found" error.

Answer (score 2):

technically, you can find a user if you know the username and the passwort (hash).

However, since the hash usually is salted with a random salt, you can't find a user by username and plain text password.

The clean approach here is to fetch the user by username and check the password (via [password_verify](https://www.php.net/password_verify) or [the symfony version](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony-security/user-password#checking-the-password) (or see [yivi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57559809/4275413))).

Answer (score 0):

I think to pass multiple criteria, you have to use the "findBy" method

```
$username= $request->request->get('username');
$password = $request->request->get('password');
$user= $this->em->getRepository(User::class)->findBy(
             [
               'username' => $username,
               'password'=> $password
             ],
             [], 
             1
);
return  new Response($user);
```

[You can find detail explanation of doctrine methods here](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/working-with-objects.html)

Comment: Rehan, as explained in other places, you can't search a username by password. This advise is wrong. Good luck!

Answer (score -2):

You could create a new method inside your repository (App/Repository/UserRepository.php)
where you can give username and password too and send back the result.

```php
public function getUserByUsernameAndPassword(string $username, string $password)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
      ->andWhere('u.username = :username')
      ->andWhere('u.password LIKE :password')
      ->setParameter('username',  $username )
      ->setParameter('password',  $password )
      ->getQuery();

    return $qb->getResult();
}
```

Comment: I am afraid this is completely wrong. Passwords are not saved in plain text in the DB, so querying for them wouldn't work.

Comment: @yivi It depends how you call this function in the repository. If you hash your password in the controller this will work fine.

Comment: No, Viperium. If you are using `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` (**as you should**), the hash you create will include a random salt and won't match what you have in the DB. [This is very easily demonstrated](https://3v4l.org/jtBKN).